Apt issues on Ubuntu 24.04 with noble-backports source
I run
apt-get  upgrade --print-uris --yes -t noble-backports
and get the following output & error:
E: The value 'noble-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

however:
apt-get  -u dist-upgrade --print-uris --yes -t noble-updates
works fine.
A normal
apt-get update
yields
Hit:2 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble-updates InRelease
Hit:3 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble-backports InRelease
Hit:4 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security noble-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu noble InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

so the noble-backports seems to exist in the sources and on the source server.
Why do I get the error with noble-backports?

Here is the solution to fix it.
